# Walkthrough step "XML Views"

Tags: sapui5

I am a beginner in SAPUI5 and I am trying to learn it through SAP demo kit. However, I am having some problem with the [step 4](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1409791afe4747319a3b23a1e2fc7064).

I did as mentioned in the tutorial but I am always getting an error saying that resource cannot be loaded.

The view is created under webcontent in a folder named VIEW and the name of view is APP.

so Project->webcontent->View->app.xml

Error is

> Error: resource view/App.view.xml could not be loaded from ./view/App.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Reason: Not Found

Here is the code in my view.

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Text text="Hello World"/>
</mvc:View>
```

And in Index file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
      src='resources/sap-ui-core.js'
      data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
      data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
      data-sap-ui-compatVersion='edge'
      data-sap-ui-preload='async'>
    </script>
    <script>
      sap.ui.localResources("view.App");
      sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.ui.xmlview({
          viewName: "view.App"
        }).placeAt("content");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if I program in a different way, it works. Please check the code below:

```
<mvc:View
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="view.app">
  <Text text="Hello World"/>
</mvc:View>
```

In index file

```
<script>
  sap.ui.localResources("view.app");
  var app = new sap.m.App({
   initialPage:"idmain1"
  });
  var page = sap.ui.view({
    id: "idmain1",
    viewName: "view.app",
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
  });
  app.addPage(page);
  app.placeAt("content");
</script>
```

Comment: if you are using eclipse can you also please upload a screenshot for your folder structure from project explorer.

Comment: I got my code working with the same code you posted above.

Comment: I am not able to paste the screen shot but I will explain the structure. so the main folder is PROJECT->Webcontent->View->app.xml     , let me know in case more information is required.

Comment: can you please send me your folder structure ? Just to be sure I am using two different ways , it works with the second example in my question but with the first one it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue looking at your description is the folder where the views are placed are named as View

**so Project->webcontent->View->app.xml**

Code is

```
sap.ui.localResources("view.App");
         sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
             new sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewName: "view.App"
        }).placeAt("content");
         });
```

So 3 issues

1. Folder name is View ====> code is called as view(case sensitive).
2. View is called app.xml =====> Code is invoked as App(case
   sensitive again)
3. The views are generally called app.view.xml but
   you structure says as app.xml need to check this as well.

By fixing these the app should render.

Comment: Yes it is app.view.xml only, I didn't mention. It worked after changing the case, thanks a lot for your help. The only problem was with the case, so point 1 and 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check View path in manifest.json ,When creating XML view function has created like this

```
"routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "async": true,
                "viewPath": "First.UI5.view",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "idAppControl",
                "clearControlAggregation": false
            },

For Example View name is FirstView, we want add viewname in  viewpath 
"viewPath": "First.UI5.view.FirstView".
```